# What's the equivalent to "typo" in handwritten texts?

Tags: word-choice

"Typos" are acknowledged as "technical" errors, ones that obviously aren't caused by the writer's poor spelling. Although less frequent than in typing, they can also occur in handwritten texts, as a result of absent-mindedness or just an accidental stroke of the pen.   Since the text wasn't actually typed, it sounds funny to call them "typos". Is there a more fitting word, one that reflects the "accidental" nature of the error?

Comment: I tend to call them _writos_ or _pennos_, but I doubt either is particularly well-established.

Comment: *Before the arrival of printing, the "copyist's mistake" or "scribal error" was the equivalent for manuscripts. * Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Dysgraphia isn’t limited to typowriters, you know. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use the phrase *slip of the pen*.  From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slip_of_the_pen):

> (idiomatic) A mistake in handwriting.

Formally, there's always *lapsus calami*.  From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lapsus-calami):

> *formal* A slip of the pen.

Informally, you could get away with [Janus Bahs Jacquet's suggestions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196365/whats-the-equivalent-to-typo-in-handwritten-texts#comment413591_196365) or the like, apparently patterned after *typo*:

> I tend to call them **writos** or **pennos**, but I doubt either is particularly well-established. *(emphasis added)*

Or the less specific terms *mistake*, *error*, etc.  There are a lot of ways you can describe this sort of error, I think.

Comment: pina colada = strained pineapple. peno colada = strained pen.

Answer (score 7):

*Lapsus* is a common formalism for inadvertent error, and you could use *lapsus calami* specifically for writing, though it is far less common than *lapsus linguae* for speaking. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsus) suggests *lapsus clavis* for keyboard errors, but that may be a step too far).

Or you could just use the English 'slip of the pen/tongue/fingers'.

Comment: I cant seem to find "Lapsus" in any dictionary also very few results about it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

mistake, spelling error, brain fart. It really is whatever you choose to name it.