# What do you call a written “Typo”

Tags: single-word-requests

The usual flow of electronic communication is added to at Christmas by many written notes and greetings hand-written in haste, among which are mistakes. “Xmas Peas and Love” comes to mind.

We term such slips *typos* when in printed or electronic form, a shortened form of

> typographical error
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo)

Other than the long phrase *slip of the pen*, do we have a similar short term for a hand-written error?

Comment: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/196365/400257) might help you.

Comment: Thanks to those who pointed me at earlier posts. *Lapsus* is a rather high register term but will do quite nicely.